# How do I add custom url in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-url

I just installed a new plguin in wordpress, and found out that the plugin uses a custom url like /?m=value. How do i add custom url?? Do I call it a custom url or ??

Thanks,
Moon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get some parameters through URLs, you can pass it like http://myurl.com/page/?param1=123&param2=123&param3=123.. and get then in the php with the $_GET.

$myvar1 = $_GET['param1'];
$myvar2 = $_GET['param2'];
$myvar3 = $_GET['param3'];